# How to build winform application including Process Diagram composed by module as Rapidminer did in its software based on Java

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, diagram

I am working on writing a software based on c#, winform. The target of the software is to allow user to finish a process design. The process must include many steps, like reading data, check data, output graphics. All these sub step is kind like a object. For easy of use and better visualizaiton, I would like to pre-design the sub step as module and allow use to drag the pre-defined modules into a space and connect them and also compile them to check validity and let them finally run the process.

I found a nice software calld rapidminer which is something having similar module concept I described above. [image]

as you can see that you could drag some nice math module into central white space and connect them togehter to form a complete modeling process.

How could I create similar function in c# winform software by visual studio?

thanks lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Rehosted Designer to do runtime design of workflow from MS. It is perfect and beautiful.